# Как удалить все буквы из строки в python?

Tags: python

Допустим, у меня есть:

```
q = "пар234ус"
```

и я хочу удалить  в ней все буквы. Kак мне это сделать без регулярных выражений ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
q = ''.join(i for i in q if not i.isalpha())
```

Comment: Да, но я не понял как это вывести на экран.

Comment: @DenMine `print(''.join(i for i in q if not i.isalpha()))` ?

Comment: А можно ответ сохранить в переменной ?

Comment: @DenMine Так он же сохраняется в той же переменной `q` ;)

Comment: нет.. Я пишу print(z) у меня с буквами принтится..

Comment: @DenMine `q = "пар234ус";q = ''.join(i for i in q if not i.isalpha());print(q)`

Comment: У меня питон 3.8 и я не знаю почему у меня не работает это. Принтится "пар234ус"

Comment: @DenMine https://i.stack.imgur.com/us3h9.gif

Comment: @DenMine Ну ок. удачи!

Answer (score 3):

Вот так вот:

```py
import itertools

q = "пар234ус"

print(''.join(itertools.filterfalse(str.isalpha, q)))
```